# How to add tags using Geolocation with Tags Input?

Tags: autocomplete, google-geolocation, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to add tags input of google geolocation address.

I am using this geolocation
[Autofill Address + Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061125/autofill-address-google-maps-api?answertab=active#answer-6855490)

This is bootstrap tags input.
http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

If I type address and select autocomplete address it should convert in a tag like bootstrap tags.

Answer (score 0):

My solution using Twitter Typeahead with bootstrap tags-input:

```
        var locations = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('formatted_address'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            identify: function (obj) {
                return obj.place_id;
            },
            remote: {
                url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%QUERY&language={YOUR_LANGUAGE}&key={YOUR_MAPS_API_KEY}',
                wildcard: '%QUERY',
                rateLimitWait: 100,
                transform: function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 'OK') {
                        return response.results;
                    } else {
                        return [];
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        $('input').tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'place_id',
            itemText: 'formatted_address',
            typeaheadjs: [{
                highlight: true
            }, {
                displayKey: 'formatted_address',
                source: locations
            }],
            trimValue: true
        });
```