# Google API for address autocompletion not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-api, siebel

I was trying to implement an Address auto-complete functionality using Google API on one of my text field in my Siebel application. I keep getting the error "google not defined".I am using jquery The following is my code:

```
     PhoneChangePR.prototype.BindData = function(a) {
                SiebelAppFacade.PhoneChangePR.superclass.BindData.call(this, a);
$.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", function() {
            console.log("Google maps successfully added");
            });
                  $.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU", function() {
            console.log("Second script loaded successfully");
            });


             var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("input[aria-labelledby=NewAddressLine1_Label]")[0], {});

                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    console.log(place.address_components);
    });
```

Kindly help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `google not defined` usually happens when maps api js didn't load. So be sure you're loading your script correctly.

Comment: I got the solution for this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061125/autofill-address-google-maps-api
It seemed to work when I tried it out on an online platform.All I have done is I have changed the name of the element.

Comment: I'm curious what you're doing with the jQuery... you're using jQuery when you refer to `$.getScript()`, but then you're loading in `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js`... but you must already have jQuery available in your page at that point!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the google maps API asynchronously, but you're trying to call the `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` constructor before the API has been loaded in.

Move all the code that relies on the API being loaded into the success callback.

```js
PhoneChangePR.prototype.BindData = function(a) {
    SiebelAppFacade.PhoneChangePR.superclass.BindData.call(this, a);
    $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", function() {
        console.log("jQuery successfully loaded");
    });

    $.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU", function() {
        console.log("Google maps successfully added");
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("input[aria-labelledby=NewAddressLine1_Label]")[0], {});

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place.address_components);
        });
    });
});
```

Instead of relying on jQuery's success callback, you might want to use Google's own callback when the maps JS has loaded successfully, by adding the `callback` URL parameter onto the request to load the Maps API.  Try this instead:

```js
PhoneChangePR.prototype.BindData = function(a) {
    SiebelAppFacade.PhoneChangePR.superclass.BindData.call(this, a);
    $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", function() {
        console.log("jQuery successfully loaded");
    });

    $.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU&callback=setupAutocomplete");
});

function setupAutocomplete() {
    console.log("Google maps successfully added");
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("input[aria-labelledby=NewAddressLine1_Label]")[0], {});

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place.address_components);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi,
The above solution works sometimes.But most of the time I am getting the error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

Can u suggest me a solution?Thanks

Comment: @GeethuAnnJoseph I've updated my answer with an alternative way to call the autocomplete code once the maps js has loaded

Comment: it still doesn't work.
I'm getting the error:
Uncaught TypeError: window.setupAutocomplete is not a function

as well as the previous error.Kindly help.Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. Maybe a complication with how your JS framework is setup. See this simple working example http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7cu2f/